# Is there a way in Chrome Tools where I can highlight a line of code and see where the JS is derived?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

I''m trying to locate where a certain object (widgets) is iterated after inspecting the element in dev tools. I was curious if there is a way to use dev tools to find out where this is happening?

```
<li ng-repeat="widget in dashboard.widgets"> ... </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Batarang Chrome Tools plugin (free at chrome store).
I believe it will help you see what you are looking for:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

You can also try opening Chrome Tools, then clicking Sources tab and digging down through the JS files, searching for the "dashboard.widgets" in the source files.

Of course if the source files are all minified that will be difficult also.
[image: sources...chrome tools]

Comment: I have batarang, but I still don't know how to use it to locate the file with this object

Comment: I edited to add another way (with pic) you might find the item using Chrome Tools.